# How to sample discrete distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, geometric-probability

Suppose $0<p_i<1$ for $i=1...n$. Then we have a series of weights
$\pi_i$ defined below:
$$\pi_i=p_i\Pi_{j=1,i-1}(1-p_j)$$
 Here is the problem:
firstly,I want to sample an $i_1$ according to the weight $\pi_i$; 
secondly, after I sampled one $i_1$, I want to sample an $i_2(i_2>i1)$ according to the weight $\pi_i$; ...;the process goes on until I sample an 
$i_k$ such that $i_k>n$.

Can someone gives some hint about how to do it efficiently? I know about the Walker table technique, but it can only help when sample $i_1$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, $p_i = \Pr(I=i|I\ge i)$ while $\pi_i=\Pr(I=i)$.
Also, $S_i^{(1)}=\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}(1-p_j)=\Pr(I\ge i)$ (a sort of survival function). Therefore, you can draw $Z_1 \sim Unif(0,1)$ and then choose $i_1 = \max\{k \,|\, S_k^{(1)}>Z_1\}$. You then choose $i_2$ with a similar procedure but under the condition $i_2>i_1$, i.e. $S_i^{(2)}=\prod_{j=i_1+1}^{i-1}(1-p_j)=\Pr(I\ge i|I>i_1)$, draw $Z_2 \sim Unif(0,1)$ and then choose $i_2 = \max\{k \,|\, S_k^{(2)}>Z_2\}$. And same for the following elements, until you hit $n$. I may have gotten some index wrong but I hope you get the gist.

Another approach could be to generate a series of $n$ Bernoulli variates and then $i_1$ is the index of the first 1 in the series, $i_2$ is the index of the second 1, etc.

This second approach is less efficient because it requires $n$ random draws while the first method generally requires a smaller number (especially if the $p_i$s are small). In terms of computation time, it depends on the language. In C, the first one would be significantly faster. In vectorized languages, like python or matlab, the second one may be faster.

The sample implementations below implement the two methods in python (please note that python uses zero-based indices).

```
import numpy as np

def sample1(p):
    i = []
    Z = np.random.rand()
    S = 1
    for k in range(len(p)):
        if S < Z:
            i.append(k - 1)
            Z = np.random.rand()
            S = 1
        S *= (1 - p[k])
    if S < Z:
        i.append(len(p) - 1)
    return i

def sample2(p):
    Z = np.random.rand(len(p)) < p
    return np.nonzero(Z)[0]

p = np.random.rand(15)
print('zero-based indices: ', sample1(p))
print('zero-based indices: ', sample2(p))
```

Because of the overhead added by the interpreter, the first method is slower than the second one. If you implemented the same logic in C, the first one would be faster than the second one.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the first "Therefore" and  choose $i_1 =max\{k|...\}$ seems not efficient enough.  The problem I asked is some thing like "inhomogenious" Bernoulli process, I want to sample the time something happens.

Comment: When generating random variables, efficiency is often interpreted as the number of random draws you need to make to generate one target random variable. With the method I suggested you draw one uniformly distributed random number for each $i_k$ you want to generate. Another approach could be to generate a series of $n$ Bernoulli variates and then $i_1$ is the index of the first 1 in the series, $i_2$ is the index of the second 1, etc. This approach is less efficient because it requires $n$ random draws while my method generally requires a smaller number (especially if the $p_i$s are small).

Comment: But it takes too much time to find the $i_1$.

Comment: Finding $i_1$ is not expensive. You compute the next $S_k$ and if it's smaller than $Z$ you stop, otherwise you increase $k$ and check again. I have added sample code.